# Hyphens in csv columns/unknown data causing int conversion errors

Tags: python, csv

I know how to convert between data types. Unfortunately, something in the data is obviating my `str` to `int` conversion during the cleaning process.

My code executes normally when I don't cast to an `int`. When I examined the csv file I realized that there are hyphens in the `BeginDate` and `EndDate` columns. I thought this was the reason for me `ValueError`, but have learned in the comments that this is not the case.

[image]

raw text

[image]

```
from csv import reader
opened_file = open('/Users/tymac/Artworks.csv')
read_data = reader(opened_file)
moma = list(read_data)
moma_header = moma[0]
moma = moma[1:]

    for row in moma:
        bd = row[5] # BeginDate
        bd = bd.replace("(", "")
        bd = bd.replace(")", "")
        #bd = int(bd)

        # I've stopped the loop after the first row "moma[0]",
        # therefore no other cells should be causing the error.
        if row == moma[0]: 
            print(bd)
            print(type(bd))
```

Comment: Have you looked at the raw csv, not viewed from excel? Sometimes negative numbers are represented by parenthesis. I wonder if that is your case. I'd open up the csv with notepad or the like and see what the raw data looks like.

Comment: Wow. I din't know that. yes it's `(1841)` indeed.  Ok so why can't I convert to int?

Comment: That I don't have an answer for. Perhaps paste a sample of your raw data here and it might add some light. Try putting a print(bd) statement right before the int conversion to see what your value looks like.

Comment: for testing, surround your conversion to int in a try/except block. In the except block, print bd. That will tell show you the cell that is failing. I suspect you will find that in one of your rows the cell is not an integer.

Comment: So the "hyphens" in the title is not correct at all, and you are actually asking about parentheses? Please fix the title if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments section, you discovered that the parenthesis represents a negative number. Almost certainly, you have a cell that that is not an integer type. An easy way to find the issue is to wrap your conversion in a try/except. For now, just print the cell - later, you will need to decide what to do with it.

```
from csv import reader
opened_file = open('/Users/tymac/Artworks.csv')
read_data = reader(opened_file)
moma = list(read_data)
moma_header = moma[0]
moma = moma[1:]

for row in moma:
    bd = row[5]
    bd = bd.replace("(", "")
    bd = bd.replace(")", "")
    try:
        bd = int(bd)
    except ValueError:
        print(bd) # Just to find your bad cell, otherwise choose what to do with it.
```

For example, if I have a csv with the following data;

```
FName, LName, Number
James, Jones, (20)
Sam, Smith, (30)
Someone, Else, nan
```

and I run the code (changing to row[2] instead of row[5]), I will get a printed result of "nan" because the conversion to int fails. This tells me that I have a row that contains something other than an iteger.

Comment: Because in your edited code, you are not converting to int. It doesn't really tell anything. I think that your issue is likely with another row. Running the code as shown should help identify that. I think you will have a value of bd printed that is obviously not an integer and it will then become clear.

Comment: Thanks. What I was trying to say is that in my code I am looping only once at exactly the first row `if row == moma[0]`. That was my edit so maybe you didn't see it. So even if there is some bad data, it should matter because I am only looping one time at `moma[0]`. I added the exception block and VS Code has returned all the birthdays. I'm not sure what you want to me look for. I see some blank spaces but I'm not looping through those rows.

Comment: Again, you won't see an error after your edit because you aren't doing a conversion to int. If go back to your original code with your original error, you were getting ValueError. I assert that is due to a bad cell, The code I posted here helps find that bad cell. Sorry, I'm not sure how better to say it. I'm afraid that is all I have for you : )

Answer (score 2):

Adding my own answer because this was the *solution* in code. SteveJ's comments led me to ask myself questions resulting in absolute filters so I marked his answer as correct.

I didn't know **a number with a leading zero is not an integer** in Python. Some of the cells started with a leading zero and certainly looked like an integer eg `0196`. In addition, I tried to use `0000` as a placeholder cell for unknown dates. The exceptions to the leading zero rule in Python are numbers that contain all zeros like `0000`. However,  since I was filtering out zeros with other conditions, it was safer to use `1111` as my placeholder integer.

I had to get aggressive with the cleaning and create filters that eliminated all possible outliers *even though I could not see them*. A "Just In Case Filter" to filter out everything that did not leave me with a 4 digit number string. Now I have 4 digit year integers with `1111` integer placeholder cells so all is good.

In the end, I was able to clean it using these filters.

```
def clean_date(string):
    bad_chars = ["(", ")", "\n", "\r", "\t"]
    for char in bad_chars:
        string = string.replace(char, "")
    if len(string) > 4:
        string = string[:4]
    elif len(string) < 4:
        string = "1111" # Don't use "0000" for padding, placeholders etc.
    elif " " in string:
        string = "1111"
    elif string.isdigit() == False: 
        string = "1111"
    elif len(string.split('1', 1)[0]):
        string = "1111"
    return string

for row in moma:
    bd = row[5] # BeginDate/Birth Date
    bd = clean_date(bd)
    bd = int(bd) # Conversion

    if row == moma[0]:
    print(bd)
    print(type(bd))

 # Date of birth as an int
 # 1841 <class 'int'>
```